# KMDF 1.11 Get process that initiates request

Tags: c++, windows, kmdf

I'm writing a driver that listens for requests on specific devices by registering for EvtIoDeviceControl.

```
DF_IO_QUEUE_CONFIG_INIT_DEFAULT_QUEUE(&IoCallbacks, WdfIoQueueDispatchParallel);
IoCallbacks.PowerManaged = WdfFalse;
IoCallbacks.EvtIoDeviceControl = EvtIoDeviceControlCallback;
```

On Windows 10 (KMDF 1.21), I can use `WdfRequestGetRequestorProcessId` to get the process ID of the process that made the request in the EvtIoDeviceControlCallback, but I'm having trouble finding a way to do this one earlier versions of KMDF. Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`WdfRequestWdmGetIrp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550037(v=vs.85).aspx) (*Minimum KMDF version 1.0*) and [`IoGetRequestorProcessId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548391(v=vs.85).aspx)

so simply use

```
ULONG WdfRequestGetRequestorProcessId_1_0(WDFREQUEST Request)
{
    return IoGetRequestorProcessId(WdfRequestWdmGetIrp(Request));
}
```